# How to setup python, numpy and openCV in windows 8.1 64 bit machine

Tags: python, opencv

It runs on windows 8.1 64 bit machine, I have installed python 2.7.8 and numpy 1.5.1 (earlier had 1.9.1) and openCV 2.4.10. I got this error referred other blogspots, stackoverflow previous questions but couldn't get the right results. I think it has something to do with 64/32 bit version compatibility please help me out!!!

**command line:**

```
C:\Users\Shivakumar>python

Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win 32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy

>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>>
```

Comment: try the cv2.pyd from the opencv/bin/x86 folder

Comment: tried out copying with x86 (32 bit) and x64 (64 bit) but no results

Comment: if the cv2.pyd is small (<10mb) it is dependant on the other opencv dlls at runtime, so the PATH to the correct x86 ones is required then

Comment: 32 bit has 10.3 MB and 64 bit one has 13MB ....and when i copy cv2.pyd to C:/Python27/lib/site-packages since it already has another cv2.pyd it gets replaced.....

Comment: if they're that large, they are self-contained(statically linked) and don't need the other opencv dlls. (sorry, out of ideas now)

Comment: Off-topic / Alternative way: Install the Anaconda Distribution of Python and use ```conda install opencv```. Done!